# Absolute Galois group of Laurent power seris $k((t))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, galois-theory

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$ and denote by $G$ its absolute Galois group. I heard several times that the absolute Galois group of the Laurent power series $k((t))$ is isomorphic to a semi-direct product $G\rtimes \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$, but I can't find a reference for this result. Qould you know where i can find this? Also, what makes it not hold if $k$ is of characteristic $p$?

Comment: In characteristic $0$, $\overline{k((t))}=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\overline{k}((t^{1/n}))$ and $\hat{\Bbb{Z}}\cong Gal(\overline{k((t))}/\overline{k}((t)))$ sending $t^{1/n}$ to $t^{1/n}\zeta_n^{a\bmod n}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We write $\operatorname {Gal}(F)$ for the absolute Galois group of a field $F$. Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$ and $k^s$ a separable closure.

There is an exact sequence $$1\longrightarrow \operatorname{Gal}(k^s((t)))\longrightarrow \operatorname{Gal}(k((t)))\longrightarrow \operatorname{Gal}(k)\longrightarrow 1$$

It is true since $k$ has characteristic 0 that $\operatorname{Gal}(k^s((t)))\cong \hat{ \mathbb{Z}}$. See, for example, the Wikipedia page for "quasi-finite field." One sees this by proving that $k^s((t^{1/n}))$ is the unique extension of degree $n$ of $k^s((t))$. One problem in characteristic $p$ is that $k^s((t^{1/p}))$ isn't separable, so it doesn't contribute to the Galois group (and there are several other extensions of degree $p$ which make this Galois group more complicated).

There is a section of the map $\operatorname{Gal}(k((t))) \to \operatorname{Gal}(k)$ (an automorphism of $k^s$ over $k$ gives an automorphism of $k((t))^s/k((t))$ just by fixing elements of the form $t^{1/n}$). This is probably the easiest way to see the map is surjective in the first place. So this sequence splits and expresses $\operatorname{Gal}(k((t)))$ as a semidirect product $\operatorname{Gal}(k^s((t)))\rtimes \operatorname{Gal}(k)$.

Edits: a previous version of this post contained some false facts about $k^s((t))$ for positive characteristic.